# FluidReview/SurveyMonkey Apply - webhook formatting/setup questions

Tags: php, json, webhooks, surveymonkey

I'm having trouble implementing webhooks in FluidReview (used to be SurveyMonkey Apply). Specifically, I want to send a webhook with the applicant and current application status, triggered upon any change in application state, so that we can update our CRM with the latest status data.  The problem is that I can't figure out setup the webhooks in FluidReview, and their documentation is abysmal ([Fluid Review Webhooks](https://help.fluidreview.com/hc/en-us/articles/235860147-Remote-Conditions-and-Web-Hooks), [Fluid Review Triggers](https://help.fluidreview.com/hc/en-us/articles/217134787-Triggers-Actions)).  Can anyone help me out by providing an example of setting up a simple or advanced webhook?

Steps followed thusfar:

1) I have a php endpoint on my wordpress site that uses the following code snippet to save the JSON from a webhook to the error log:

```
if(isset($_GET['fr-listener']) && $_GET['fr-listener'] == 'fr') {
    error_log("fr-listener==fr hook caught!");
    if($json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)) {
    // if($json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)) {
        error_log("JSON found");

        error_log(print_r($json,true));
        error_log(var_dump($json));
        // $data = var_export($json, true);
        // error_log("data dump: " + $data);
        // print_json($json);
    } else {
        error_log("no JSON found");
        print_r($_POST);
        $data = $_POST;
    }
}
```

I can use this to successfully catch webhooks from Stripe (I used the above snippet to help develop my Stripe webhook catcher) and get a look at their JSON contents.  When I catch one of the webhooks from FluidReview, I get the "no JSON found" response.  This is how I have the webhook set:
[My Webhook Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qnhk.png)
(URL = https://wfadev.pairsite.com/listen?fr-listener=fr, Method = POST, Request content = {{applicant.email}})

2) I have tried both setting simple and advanced webhooks, and neither of them are producing the JSON output I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more testing and it turns out that the "Request content" field is just a blank text field.  To have it send JSON data from FluidReview, write it out like this, using the piping variables ("{{variable name}}")

```
{
"first_name": "{{user.first_name}}",
"last_name":"{{user.last_name}}",
"email":"{{user.email}}",
"application_type":"{{user.}}",
"date":"{{date}}",
"trigger":"{{trigger}}"
}
```